# Vertical alignment in multicols

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

How can I prevent the white space between lines caused by vertical alignment, as seen in first and third columns from the MWE below?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %-> accepts Latin accentuation
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%... allows the user to select font encodings, and for each encoding provides an interface to ‘font-encoding-specific’ commands for each font. Its most powerful effect is to enable hyphenation to operate on texts containing any character in the font

\usepackage{multicol}
\def\deg{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\def\v#1{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Sobre as leis de Kepler}

{\footnotesize
Considere elipse de semi-eixo maior $a$, semi-eixo menor $b$, excentricidade $e$ e área $A$.

\begin{multicols}{4}
\textit{Excentricidade de elipse}
\[
    e = \frac{c}{a}
\]

\textit{Área de elipse}
\[
    A = \pi a b
\]

\textit{2\deg\ Lei de Kepler}
\[
    \frac{\Delta A}{\Delta t} = \v{constante}
\]

\textit{3\deg Lei de Kepler}
\[
    \frac{T^2}{a^3} = \v{constante}
\]

\textit{Velocidade média}
\[
    \bar{v} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
\]
\end{multicols}
}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Approaches which require manual actions (such as`\columnbreak` or replacing `multicols` by `tabular`) should be avoided.

Comment: Be careful when using `\def` that enables one to redefine existing commands without any warning. In fact, `\v` is already an existing command that adds the caron accent above a letter, e.g., `\v{C}apek` results into `Čapek`.

Comment: Thank you, @MarianG. I didn't know that. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the command `\raggedcolumns` you will not get all the whitespace in the columns.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %-> accepts Latin accentuation
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%... allows the user to select font encodings, and for each encoding provides an interface to ‘font-encoding-specific’ commands for each font. Its most powerful effect is to enable hyphenation to operate on texts containing any character in the font

\usepackage{multicol}
\def\deg{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\def\v#1{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns
\textbf{Sobre as leis de Kepler}

{\footnotesize
Considere elipse de semi-eixo maior $a$, semi-eixo menor $b$, excentricidade $e$ e área $A$.

\begin{multicols}{4}
\textit{Excentricidade de elipse}
\[
    e = \frac{c}{a}
\]

\textit{Área de elipse}
\[
    A = \pi a b
\]

\textit{2\deg\ Lei de Kepler}
\[
    \frac{\Delta A}{\Delta t} = \v{constante}
\]

\textit{3\deg Lei de Kepler}
\[
    \frac{T^2}{a^3} = \v{constante}
\]

\textit{Velocidade média}
\[
    \bar{v} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
\]
\end{multicols}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Sveinung! It works nicely.

Comment: also not have equation and text above equations vertical aligned :)

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, I am not I understand your comment. The vertical alignment, if important, I assume will be done by adjusting the how the equations are displayed (left, centered or right adjusted). Removing excessive white space will probably also help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `multicols` without `\columnbreak` results into automatic column breaking. In your simple document one could use the approach below.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %-> accepts Latin accentuation
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%... allows the user to select font encodings, and for each encoding provides an interface to ‘font-encoding-specific’ commands for each font. Its most powerful effect is to enable hyphenation to operate on texts containing any character in the font

\usepackage{multicol}
\def\deg{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\def\v#1{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Sobre as leis de Kepler}

{\footnotesize
Considere elipse de semi-eixo maior $a$, semi-eixo menor $b$, excentricidade $e$ e área $A$.

\begin{multicols}{4}
%--------------------------------
\textit{Excentricidade de elipse}
\[
    e = \frac{c}{a}
\]
\columnbreak


%--------------------------------
\textit{Área de elipse}
\[
    A = \pi a b
\]

\textit{2\deg\ Lei de Kepler}
\[
    \frac{\Delta A}{\Delta t} = \v{constante}
\]


%--------------------------------
\textit{3\deg Lei de Kepler}
\[
    \frac{T^2}{a^3} = \v{constante}
\]
\columnbreak


%--------------------------------    
\textit{Velocidade média}
\[
    \bar{v} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
\]
\end{multicols}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, @MarianG. Thank you for your response. But someone else has already presented this solution. It is deleted after I claim that manual break is not a good solution to the problem.

Comment: @Brasil: I don't see any mention about the manual justification in your original question. You should edit your question. Otherwise, our effort is wasted.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will edit it. :D

Answer (score -1):

Let me share another simple approach that is also acceptable and, in fact, is the one I chose to use. In this case, I defined the command `\setinfo` that takes two arguments: the title and its mathematical definition. In this way, I prevent the title to be separated from its mathematical definition by a column or page break. In addition, edits are easy to be performed, since I don't have a complete table, but separated and independent ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %-> accepts Latin accentuation
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%... allows the user to select font encodings, and for each encoding provides an interface to ‘font-encoding-specific’ commands for each font. Its most powerful effect is to enable hyphenation to operate on texts containing any character in the font

\usepackage{multicol}
\def\deg{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\def\v#1{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\setinfo}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \textit{#1} \\ \multicolumn{1}{r}{$\displaystyle #2$}
    \end{tabular}
    }

\begin{document}

\textbf{Sobre as leis de Kepler}

{\footnotesize
Considere elipse de semi-eixo maior $a$, semi-eixo menor $b$, excentricidade $e$ e área $A$.

\begin{multicols}{4}
\setinfo{Excentricidade de elipse}{e = \frac{c}{a}}

\setinfo{Área de elipse}{A = \pi a b}

\setinfo{2\deg\ Lei de Kepler}{\frac{\Delta A}{\Delta t} = \v{constante}}

\setinfo{3\deg Lei de Kepler}{\frac{T^2}{a^3} = \v{constante}}

\setinfo{Velocidade média}{\bar{v} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}}
\end{multicols}
}

\end{document}
```